# Animating a div when expand

Tags: css

I have a div that contains h1, h2 and a button.
When I click the button, the button is hidden and instead there's a form with 2 text inputs.
The div is always centered, whenever is expand or not (with flex).
I want that on clicking the button, the div (with its new larger size) will move up (with animation), but still stay in the center.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This isn't a place where developers write code for you for free. It's a place where developers help each other with their code. Please create an [mcve] to show what you've tried so far, and describe what isn't working and your desired result.

Comment: “will move up but still stay in the center” - do you mean that the form is revealed slowly so that the size of the div increases slowly but it’s always centered?

Comment: please add your code in a snippet. I can't understand what exactly you need without your code.